# How to find where an Objective-C object is referenced from?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm using the Allocations instrument in Xcode to track an object that is being created but not released.  I can see the object count increase as the code executes, and I can see where the objects are being created using the call stack, but I can't tell where the object references are being held.  I think they're being held in a 3rd-party library, but the developer says "no, it must be your code".  I'm setting the references in my code to nil, but the objects remain.

Comment: Does your code use ARC?  Does the third party code use ARC?

Comment: Of course ARC is the best way.

Comment: My code is using ARC.  I don't know if the 3rd party code is, but I can find out given time.  Basically, somewhere a reference is being held which is preventing the object from being released, but I can't find out where the reference is being held.  It *might* be my code, it might not.

Comment: @mjtitus: You should be able to see the history of retains and releases on the object using Instruments. The same Allocations instrument will do this if you turn on the "Record reference counts" option in the instrument's info panel. With this info, you can then figure out what code is responsible for each retain and each autorelease/release, and therefore figure out what's keeping it alive.

Comment: The history of retains and releases for the object in question shows 226 events, mostly coming from libdispatch.dylib.  What I really need is a tool that, for any point in time, shows me exactly where each pointer reference resides.  I suspect that the problem is that Class A creates the object and hands it off to Class B which sticks it in a data structure.  I want a tool that can tell me a reference exists in Class B "at this point in time".

Comment: Instruments will happily tell you this. Look at the history for the object. What object caused it to be retained? That is what you are looking for. You can move forward and backward in the allocations trace and see the history change.

Comment: Post the trace, or a screenshot of it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there exists a tool that will tell you where each reference is at any point in time. As you're using ARC, in my experience, there are two fairly common ways to get yourself caught in a reference cycle and leak memory:

1. Class A has a strong reference to an instance of class B, which has a strongly reference to the same instance of class A.
2. Blocks implicitly retain references to objects it captures. So one obvious gotcha is when your object retains a block which retains a reference to self.

**Example:**

```
self.retainedBlock = ^{
    [self doSomething];
};
```

**Fix:**

```
__weak id weakSelf = self;
self.retainedBlock = ^{
    id strongSelf = weakSelf;
    [strongSelf doSomething];
};
```

Answer (score -1):

It's a desperation ploy but what you could do is:

1. disable ARC for the affected object (or work around it; see below);
2. add a logging `retain`, `autorelease` and `release`;
3. trace a known over-retained object through your logs.

The simplest example:

```
- (void)release
{
    NSLog(@"%@ : %@", self, [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
    [super release];
}
```

(though, in practice, it's probably a lot smarter to keep an array of `[NSThread callStackSymbols]` for the memory management calls in a dictionary indexed by e.g. `[NSValue valueWithPointer:self]`, then to access that either from lldb or by writing it to disk; why bother effectively indexing the data by hand?)

Probably the easiest way to work around ARC is to write a single class with ARC disabled that can method swizzle your logging memory management methods onto the objects you want to track.